# Change Multi line strings to Single line

Tags: javascript

Hi I have some text in following format,

683101,
682303,
682302,
682315,
683581,
686667,
682008,
683572,
683573,
682313,
686672,
683545 etc....

Each line break'ed into next line with "Enter". I have nearly 2000 lines of text like this. i want o display the above string to a single line like this. 
 
683101,
682303,
682302,
682315,
683581,
686667,
682008,
683572,
683573,
682313,
686672,
683545,
686672,
683545 etc..

I think there is some tweak options in CSS for doing this. Is there a way in JavaScript to do this? Actually it is not a requirement for me, am just curious to know how it is done.

- **Edit:**

In My text editor it looks like this,

[image]

When i try to run it, this is what i get.

[image]

Thats why i want to remove the enter, multiline.......

Comment: You need to add \ at the end of each line for multi-line strings

Comment: I know adding slash at the end of the line can solve this. i want to know is there any way to do this programatically or why it is not possible.

Comment: Because, Javascript's automatic semicolon insertion adds `;` at the end of each line, that is causing error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a simple way for this. You can do this without extra code. Just write like this -

```
var str = "12345,\
234234,\
234324,\
234324,\
234324,\
234234";
```

now just add a slash

Ok, If you don't want to use the above method then use another plan is -

take inside an array and after that use the join method

```
var str = [12345,
234234,
234324,
234324,
234324,
234234];


str.join(",");
```

If we are using ES6, Then we have an elegant way to do this using **Backtick** -

```
var str = `12345,
234234,
234324,
234324,
234324,
234234`;
```

Comment: Tushar has already suggested it in the comment above and i always use '\' to resolve this. I want to know if there some other way to do this without adding 'slash'.

Comment: Works, though I'm very sad that Apple considers something like "blah blah, \ blah" acceptable. It's so unreadable it's ridiculous.

Comment: The last one saved my life. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can use Regular expression to remove all the linebreaks and replace them using space.

```
str = str.replace(/\n/g, ' ');
```

Here, `\n` will match all the line-breaks, and replace them by *space*

Comment: Just one slash `str.replace(/\n/g, ' ')`

Answer (score 1):

Since your data is already comma separated, you can try to add "**[**" to the beginning and append " **].toString().replace(/\n/g," ")** " to the end of your data to get a single line string like this:

```
[683101,
682303,
682302,
682315,
683581,
686667,
682008,
683572,
683573,
682313,
686672,
683545].toString().replace(/\\n/g," ")
```

then you get: 
**"683101,682303,682302,682315,683581,686667,682008,683572,683573,682313,686672,683545"**

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to put those values in one line then, you can set those values as the value of a textarea field. This will allow you to read all those values into a javascript string. Afterward you can apply the regular expression that Tushar suggested.

See the code segment below:

```
<textarea id="content">
683101,
682303,
682302,
682315,
683581,
686667,
682008,
683572,
683573,
682313,
686672,
683545
</textarea>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
var content = $('#content').val();
var content = content.replace(/\n/g, ' ');
console.log(content);
```